# Excel Equation generating statement if value is outside range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am writing as my equation is not working. It is for a lab spread sheet.

I essentially want a statement to be generated if the value is above 0.2 or below 0.0025 as the limits.

Currently the statement is being generated even when it is not violating the criteria.

Feedback welcome on the below equation:

```excel-formula
=IF(X18="", "", IF(OR(((X11-X14)>0.2), ((X11-X14)<0.0025), ((X12-X14)>0.2), ((X12-X14)<0.0025), ((Y11-YY14)>0.2), ((Y11-Y14)<0.0025), ((Y12-Y14)>0.2), ((Y12-Y14)<0.0025)),"Mass Exceeds Criteria; Results estimated", ""))
```

Comment: you have a typo `((Y11-YY14)>0.2)` should be `((Y11-Y14)>0.2)`

Comment: oh gosh, thanks. That was totally it.